# How do I keep my discord bot online even with my terminal closed

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, pm2, forever

I have a pretty simple discord.js bot and would like to keep it running even when I close my terminal and/or my computer.

I have already tried pm2 and just keeping my terminal open throughout the day, but it wastes battery.

I keep running `pm2 run NAMEOFFILE.JS` in the right folder, but it already says I'm running the file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Yeah use PM2 or some other application, screen is a bad idea.

If you're on either MacOS or Linux, you can use the screen command (Or cygwin on Windows). It basically creates another terminal. To use it you can do `screen -R <name>`.

When you use the `-R <name>` (capital) the computer will look for a screen with the name and reattach to it. If it can't find a screen with that name it will create a new screen with that name.

So for you, you might do `screen -R Discord`. After you attach to the screen you can do whatever you want as if it were a terminal. When you're done, you can press `ctrl+a` then `d` to detach from the screen, then you can close the terminal window.

https://ss64.com/osx/screen.html

Answer (score 2):

You must use a process manager, like pm2 (`pm2 start yourfile.js`) or forever (`forever start yourfile.js`). You can install them with npm (`npm i -g pm2`, `npm i -g forever`).

Comment: So I tried this and I did `forever start myfile.js` but it kept saying that if my script was open for less than 1000ms then it would exit it. I kept my script open, but it still kept stopping my code.